# JavaScript localStorage NaN error

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a game with html and JavaScript. A saving system is included into the game I did this with localStorage. When I open the html file from my computer everything goes fine. Everything saves in localStorage and everything loads perfectly... But when I uploaded the files to my website where the game is located On every value there comes NaN... I know that means Not a Number but I do not get it. Why does this work on my computer but not on my website?

Here is the saving and loading part of the game!

```
var save_format=1;
function save(){
    localStorage.setItem("game_saved_before", save_format);
    localStorage.setItem("Money", Money);
    localStorage.setItem("DrinksSold", DrinksSold);
    localStorage.setItem("Price", Price);
    localStorage.setItem("Plants", Plants);
    localStorage.setItem("CompetitorBonus", CompetitorBonus);
    localStorage.setItem("Meals", Meals);
    localStorage.setItem("MealsLeft", MealsLeft);
    localStorage.setItem("MealCost", MealCost);
    localStorage.setItem("Werknemers", Werknemers);
    localStorage.setItem("WerknemerCost", WerknemerCost);
    localStorage.setItem("nextCostWerknemer", nextCostWerknemer);
    localStorage.setItem("StreetLicenses", StreetLicenses);
    localStorage.setItem("StreetLicensesHomeTown", StreetLicensesHomeTown);
    localStorage.setItem("StreetLicenseCost", StreetLicenseCost);
    localStorage.setItem("nextCostStreetLicense", nextCostStreetLicense);
    localStorage.setItem("HigherPriceCost", HigherPriceCost);
    localStorage.setItem("nextHigherPriceCost", nextHigherPriceCost);
    localStorage.setItem("PlantCost", PlantCost);
    localStorage.setItem("nextPlantCost", nextPlantCost);   
    localStorage.setItem("nextMealCost", nextMealCost);
    localStorage.setItem("DestroyCompetitorCost", DestroyCompetitorCost);
}


function load_game(){
    if(parseInt(localStorage.getItem("game_saved_before") === save_format){
    if(localStorage.getItem("game_saved_before") !== null){
    // or:
    if(localStorage["game_saved_before"] !== undefined){
    // or:
    if(typeof(localStorage.getItem("game_saved_before")) !== "string"){
        Money = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("Money"));
        DrinksSold = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("DrinksSold"));
        Price = parseFloat(localStorage.getItem("Price"));
        Plants = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("Plants"));
        CompetitorBonus = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("CompetitorBonus"));
        Meals = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("Meals"));
        MealsLeft = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("MealsLeft"));
        MealCost = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("MealCost"));
        Werknemers = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("Werknemers"));
        WerknemerCost = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("WerknemerCost"));
        nextCostWerknemer = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("nextCostWerknemer"));
        StreetLicenses = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("StreetLicenses"));
        StreetLicensesHomeTown = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("StreetLicensesHomeTown"));
        StreetLicenseCost = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("StreetLicenseCost"));
        nextCostStreetLicense = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("nextCostStreetLicense"));
        HigherPriceCost = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("HigherPriceCost"));
        nextHigherPriceCost = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("nextHigherPriceCost"));
        PlantCost = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("PlantCost"));
        nextPlantCost = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("nextPlantCost"));
        nextMealCost = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("nextMealCost"));
        DestroyCompetitorCost = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("DestroyCompetitorCost"));
    }
}
}
}
}
load_game();
setInterval(save,1000);
```

I have been thinking is it because I can't reach there localStorage? Please help me I really need this and I have been trying to find an answer for days.

Comment: Whats the value of meals,money,etc. when you call save? Are they even initialized?

Comment: As an elaboration of Ivan's question - what happens when you add the following at the start of your loadGame function?
console.log('money:',localStorage.getItem("Money"));

Comment: Well it saves every second right? so does it matter if they are innitialized with nothing in the beginning? All variables are stored with numbers...

Comment: We have no way of knowing (with the code you posted) the initial value of any of your variables (Money, DrinksSold, etc).  If any one of them isn't initialized with a number - then this is expected behaviour.

Comment: Tim, There does not happen anyhting. The webpage just runs as it normally does..

Comment: Is your browser blocking localStorage from your website or from any non-localhost source?

Comment: Oh you don't have the console open in your browser - that is a very handy thing to do - so you can see if there are any errors on your page.

But, failing that - you can change the console.log to an alert.  So:
alert('money:', localStorage.getItem("Money"));

Comment: Tim, https://gyazo.com/bf933bbedb3c5d666cc4cccc8ee288f3 This is what I see

Comment: I think you'll need to track down which (possibly all) of the numbers you're trying to "get" are coming back invalid.

To start with I'd recommend opening your browser's console window.  On chrome you can do this by clicking on "more tools" -> "developer tools" and then you can log using console.log('blah');  Failing that - you can use alert - it is a lot more intrusive and cumbersome - but just do a single alert which contains the values of all of your localStorage.getItem(..) function calls.

Comment: So yeah I did that and every variable says NaN in the browser of my website but on my computer everything works fine the saving, the loading... Link: https://gyazo.com/57a7fcd810d2d2e7445e8699f20c1e34

Comment: even if you don't wrap the get of the value with parseInt(..) they are coming back as NaN?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## issue

Your check to make sure you have localStorage values is invalid:

```
if(typeof(localStorage.getItem("game_saved_before")) != undefined){
```

getItem returns `null` and `typeof(null)` is `object`.

Consequently, all your other calls can evaluate to `parseInt(null)` which is `NaN`.

## immediate solution

A direct fix would be:

```
if(localStorage.getItem("game_saved_before") !== null){
```

or:

```
if(localStorage["game_saved_before"] !== undefined){
```

or:

```
if(typeof(localStorage.getItem("game_saved_before")) === "string"){
```

But then you have to make sure you `localStorage.clear()` to get rid of all the properties with values of "NaN".

## Adding Versioning

I think you are already running into issues of old configs that you could avoid by versioning:

```
var save_format=1; // increment on breaking save format changes

save()
   localStorage.setItem("game_saved_before", save_format)
...

load_game()
   if(parseInt(localStorage.getItem("game_saved_before")) === save_format){
...
```

A drawback of this approach is that you are still saving things piecemeal, so legacy properties from one version may end up coexisting with future versions unless you use `removeItem`.

Comment: Right I get that but what is the correct code to make sure I have localstorage values? Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you already! But now it doesn't load my game data if I reload my page.... source code: I updated the source code in the main question so you can see.. I don't know where to place my brackets or anything like that... Sorry for all of my questions/problems

Comment: @TheoDePro ah, I'd meant choose 1 of the 3 but nesting them should have worked and was a good test.. I wrote the 3rd one backwards and have now fixed it. If you correct the 3rd one (and perhaps reduce it to just one) then I think it will work as long as you are setting the values somewhere for new games. (If you aren't already setting values for a new game then an else in the load_game would be a natural pace to do it.)

Comment: So I changed !== to === in the 3d one but it does not save or load at all it just starts over new again... Sorry that it isn't running so smooth :/

Comment: so where do you setItem game_saved_before and initialize all of the variables in save() for a new player?

Comment: there was a missing parenthesis in my example, but you don't already have a place where you set this? Did you set it manually in your local testing?

Comment: So, great news! The money is saved and loaded properly but werknemers (employees), nextstreetlicensecost and streetlicenses do not work normally you can only buy 2 employees for each street license but now when I open up the game the limitations do not work and where the cost of the next street license should be there comes 'NaN'... Is this because the cost of that streetlicense is beeing calculated with multipliers and math.pow etc.? I'd like to send you the full source code to you so you can look because I don't know what to do with it :'(! But thank you already!

Comment: As you go down the list of items in save, the first one that doesn't exist is going to cause an uncaught exception preventing all subsequent ones. You can use try.. catch or check typeof(variable) != "undefined" for each. But normally you would move all of this into one object and just dump every property it has in a for loop (i.e. http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html#h_mrW9RQxlGk) but that has little to do with issue of using localStorage.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help but I think my knowledge lays too low for this kind of stuff... I'll just do without a saving system but I'll  confirm this post as solution!